# how can I prove this statement in local field theory?

Tags: valuation-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a fixed [local field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field). Then there is an integer $q=p^r$, where p is a fixed prime element of $\mathbb{K}$ and r is a positive integer [edit] such that for each $x\in\mathbb{K}, x\neq0$, we have $|x|=q^k$ for some integer $k$. [/edit]

Comment: What is $q{}{}$?

Comment: Do you mean this: “If $\Bbb K$ is a local field of characteristic zero, and $\pi$ is a prime element of $\Bbb K$, then there is $r\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\pi^r\in\Bbb Z.\quad$”  ?

Comment: I am reading this article http://docdro.id/8Vg64lu. The first two lines of page 295 is devoted to the Subject.

Comment: The presentation of $p$-adic facts in the paragraph you’re reading is very unsatisfactory. In particular, $p$ is an prime integer that is determined from the field $\Bbb K$—it’s the characteristic of the residue field— and $q$ is a specific power of that. Let me say that if you’re hoping to *learn* something about $p$-adic numbers, that article is not the place. They have written for people who already know about local fields, and are reminding their readers of the facts.

Comment: I added a sentence introducing $q$ from your source. Without it the question was IMHO non-sensical. I think that your title also needs work given that this is really about the theory of local fields.

Comment: Also, what Lubin said. If you have never seen $p$-adic fields, you are not going to enjoy reading this paper.